# Powering a 1mA - 100mV amplifier with the output of an MCU without directly supplying 1mA

Tags: current, circuit-design, boost, low-power, rfid

I'm trying to design a super low power consumption tag for RFID applications. The idea is to power all the circuitry with the I/O of the microcontroller.

I am assessing two different low power amplifiers: One based on a BJT transistor, and the other based on a tunnel diode. The former consumes 200uA at 1.8V approx (360uW). The last one consumes 100mV at 1mA (100uW). The power consumption of the second one is clearly lower.

As my MCU must operate at least at 1.8V, powering the first amplifier seems easy keeping the power consumption close to 360 uW + MCU uW. On the other, with the second amplifier, if I directly power it with the I/O, MCU had to supply 1mA at one of those pins thus resulting in 1mA*1.8V = 1.8mW.

The question: I need to convert the voltage of 1.8V and a few uA to 0.1V and 1mA. Finally, the overall power consumption of the tag should be under one mW, so using a voltage divider is not an option. What is the best option to boost the current without supplying it directly from the MCU? Maybe using a transistor?

Comment: I'm a bit confused how your power architecture looks like. Why does supplying anything from a microcontroller *save* energy? If anything, microcontrollers typically integrate linear regulators, which "burn" all the excess voltage. Can you please add a schematic drawing that shows your power source(s), and which users of power are in your system?

Comment: Generally, what you want to do sounds impossible: 1.8 V · 10 µA = 18 µW (10 is how I interpret your vague "a few"), and 0.1V · 1 mA = 100 µW, which is way more. Since conservation of energy is one of these things you can rely on as long as this universe doesn't break, I think your concept my be dead to begin with, unless there's a temporal aspect to this that you forget to mention.

Comment: Tunnel/Esaki diodes are not likely what you want. Maybe you should describe in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. To clarify a little bit. The kind of amplifier that I want is a reflection amplifier. I have made two prototypes, one using a BJT and the other using the tunnel diode (you can amplify by biasing the diode in the differential negative resistance region). The objective is to integrate it on a tag with power consumption under mA. The idea is to harvest energy from a tiny solar cell and save it into a super-cap or a LiPo battery. As the battery supplies 2 or 3V, and the MCU operates minimum at 1.8V,  the question is: (part 1)

Comment: The BJT amplifier consumes 200uA at 1.8V ( 360uW), and the diode amplifier consumes 100mV at 1mA (100uW). I have to choose one of those options and the second one seems to be the best in terms of power consumption. The problem comes when I try to generate this specific biasing condition of 100mV and 1mA for the diode amplifier. Apparently, the unique solution that I know is using several buck converters in cascade, or a regulator, but then the overall power consumption increase more than using the BJT amplifier option. (part 2)

Comment: So I figured out that even though the second amp draws three times less, it's useless because I have to waste even more power to get these 100mV 1mA bias conditions. It's sad not to be able to take advantage of those great features of the tunnel diode amplifier just because of that. (part 3)

Comment: Well, I don't mean to go against the law of conservation of energy. I would just like to know if there is any way to power up a 100uW reflection amplifier (1mA and 100mV) without screwing up this fantastic consumption by converting 2V into 100mV. I mean, I can generate 100mV with the MCU, but if the amp request 1mA at that output pin, this current is added to the consumption of the MCU (1.8V * 1mA = 1.8mW) and this is not an efficient conversion. Finally, 100uW turns into 1.8mW.